# How to find the area bounded by the curve and x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

The text says: Determine the area bounded by the curve and $x$-axis. Could somebody solve or at least explain how I should solve these problems.

- $y=x^3+1.5x^2$
- $y=-x^3-3x^2$
- $y=x^2+x+2$ and $y=-x^2+x+4$

Comment: Use definite integration.

Comment: The x-axis is given by $y=0$

Comment: yeah I understand that i must use definite integration but how to determine what should i integrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll tell you how to do the second one.

$$y = -x^3 - 3x^2$$

First of all let's find the extrema of the integration by solving those two equations:

1) Set $x = 0$ we find

$$ y = 0 $$

2) Set $y = 0$ we find

$$-x^3 - 3x^2 = 0 ~~~~~ \to ~~~~~ -x^2(x + 3) = 0 ~~~~~ \to ~~~~~ x = -3$$

Thence your extrema are $0$ and $-3$.

Finally:

$$A = \int_{-3}^0 -x^3 - 3x^2\ \text{d}x = -\frac{1}{4}x^4 - x^3 \bigg|_{-3}^0 = 0 - \left(-\frac{(-3)^4}{4} - (-3)^3\right) = 0 + \frac{81}{4} - 27 = -6.75$$

Comment: could it be that the third one result is 8/3

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'll show you how to do the first one. Above is a graph of $y=x^3+1.5x^2$.. As you can see, the region bounded by the curve and x-axis is between $x = -1.5$ and $x = 0$. Therefore you integrate between $-1.5$ and $0$ to get

\begin{equation}
\int_{-1.5}^{0} x^3+1.5x^2 dx
=
[0.25x^4 + 0.5x^3]_{x=-1.5}^0
=2.9531
\end{equation}

Comment: yes thank you but could you explain how can i find the region bounded without a graph ?

Comment: You will have to know which part is bounded between the curve and x-axis..Plotting or guessing should be done